# Flash actionscript 2 preloader quicky

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, preloader

just a quick question reguarding how to make a preloader animate backwards. So the bar decreases in width as the load number gets larger.

Here's my code

```
    onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    loading = _root.getBytesLoaded();
    total = _root.getBytesTotal();
    if (percent == undefined) percent = 0;
    percent -= (percent-((loading/total)*100))*.25;
    per = int(percent);
    percentage = per+"%";
    loadBar._width = per*9.70;
    if (percent>99) {
        _root.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simpler:

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    onEnterFrame = function () {
        loading = _root.getBytesLoaded();
        total = _root.getBytesTotal();
        percent = Number(loading/total);
        this._xscale = (1-percent)*100;
        trace(percent);
        if (percent>=1) {
            //_root.gotoAndStop(2);
            delete (onEnterFrame);
        }
    };
}
```

And it will stop after conditon (percent>=1) become true.

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
loadBar._width = per*9.70;
```

into

```
loadBar._width = (100 -per)*9.70;
```

is a quick and dirty way to do it